# How to use AJV in Firefox addon?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, ajv, web-extension

I would like to use [AJV](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv) in a Firefox addon in order to validate JSON that has been entered by the user. What file(s) of the AJV repository do I have to include in my project folder and how do I import them correctly?

Normally, I'd just use the minified version from https://cdnjs.com/libraries/ajv but Mozilla doesn't allow that.

Thank you!

Comment: Simply download the file and load it like you load any other script of your extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm Unfortunately, the AJV repo does not contain a stand-alone .js file that I could include directly.

Comment: I see `bundle` file there. If it's still incomplete you can make your own bundle by using `browserify`.

Comment: How would I do that exactly?